# How to use map and slot effectively?

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, map, version-12, slot

I want to change my code from :

```
f[n_, x_] := n Sin[x ]
 Table[{x, f[0, x], f[1, x], f[2, x], f[3, x]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi],1.0}] // Chop
```

with OUTPUT :

```
{{-3.14159, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-2.14159, 
  0, -0.841471, -1.68294, -2.52441}, {-1.14159, 
  0, -0.909297, -1.81859, -2.72789}, {-0.141593, 
  0, -0.14112, -0.28224, -0.42336}, {0.858407, 0, 0.756802, 1.5136, 
  2.27041}, {1.85841, 0, 0.958924, 1.91785, 2.87677}, {2.85841, 0, 
  0.279415, 0.558831, 0.838246}}
```

> **TO**

```
Table[{x, f[#1, x] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
   1.0}] // Chop
```

with output

```
{{-3.14159, {0, 0, 0, 
   0}}, {-2.14159, {0, -0.841471, -1.68294, -2.52441}}, {-1.14159, \
{0, -0.909297, -1.81859, -2.72789}}, {-0.141593, {0, -0.14112, \
-0.28224, -0.42336}}, {0.858407, {0, 0.756802, 1.5136, 
   2.27041}}, {1.85841, {0, 0.958924, 1.91785, 
   2.87677}}, {2.85841, {0, 0.279415, 0.558831, 0.838246}}}
```

Here in the edited code, `x` and `f[n,x]` form two separate rows. Please guide me to edit the code so that it `x` and `f` comes in one row as previously

Comment: How about `Table[Flatten@{x, f[#1, x] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}}, {x, -Pi, Pi], 1.0}] // Chop` ? I am sure there are other ways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[f, n, x]
f[n_, x_] := n Sin[x]

alist = Table[{x, f[0, x], f[1, x], f[2, x], 
    f[3, x]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 1.0}] // Chop


blist = Table[{x, 
    Splice[f[#, x] & /@ Range[0, 3]]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 1.0}] // 
  Chop


clist = Table[{x, 
    Sequence @@ (f[#, x] & /@ Range[0, 3])}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 
    1.0}] // Chop  

clist == blist == alist
```

> (* True *)

Comment: Splice doesn't work on my notebook. It is "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"

Comment: Please see update